# Отобразить контент одного домена на другом (DNS)

Tags: dns, домен, поддомены

Добрый день. Появилась интересная задача. Надо отобразить содержимое сайта 
beta.site.ru
На домене mysite.com без переадресации и iFrame. 
Есть идея, что такое можно сделать при помощи DNS, только как такое сделать я не знаю. Знает кто-нибудь, как такое сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С соседнего субдомена не будет работать, т.к. [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).
Я отойду от решения через домены и предложу более стандартные пути.

1. [XMLHttpRequest, XDomainRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain)
2. AJAX на свой домен и на стороне сервера сделать запрос в нужное место. Если нужно сохранять сессию, то можно попробовать передать session_id в параметрах.

Answer (score 0):

> такое можно сделать при помощи DNS

да, можно, с помощью [cname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record).

вот только сайт должен быть «согласен» отдать то же самое содержимое и под другим именем. с большой долей вероятности, вы получите совсем не то, что хотели бы.

---

пример из реальной жизни:

доменное имя `www.ya.ru` описано как *cname*-запись со значением `ya.ru`. но, как можете убедиться сами, сайт `ya.ru`, получив обращение под именем `www.ya.ru`, вообще не возвращает веб-страницу, а предлагает браузеру перенаправление (код ответа 302) на адрес `http://ya.ru`.